# Why hasn't Ubuntu packaged a more recent version of GDM?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gdm

I'm not sure if anyone would have the answer to this, but it seems a little odd to me that Ubuntu doesn't package the latest stable version of gdm considering gnome-shell version 3.4 was packaged in the precise release.

I know it's not a massive question, but I'm intrigued to know why this hasn't been included in the repos. I would imagine that some people want to full gnome experience and ubuntu just isn't giving it to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gdm 3.0 is the latest version included in 12.04/repos because at the time of the [UIFreeze/BetaFreeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule/),  on Feb 23, 2012, no newer version was ready -- ["gdm requires a lot of patching to work on Debian/Ubuntu."](http://jeremy.bicha.net/2012/02/01/gnome-versions-for-ubuntu-1204/)

See [this blog post](http://jeremy.bicha.net/2012/02/01/gnome-versions-for-ubuntu-1204/) from Jeremy Bicha, Ubuntu's gnome-desktop maintainer (among other things) for the reasoning behind what bits and pieces of Gnome 3.4 made it into Precise and why (or why not).

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you very much. I didn't realise how much configuring was needed to get everything running in ubuntu. I'm tempted to join the ubuntu-desktop team though to test some of the apps.

Comment: @SuperMatt You're welcome! *tista* has a GDM 3.4 PPA, but it didn't work on Precise for me. [Joining ubuntu-desktop isn't easy :(](https://launchpad.net/~developer-membership-board) (well, unless you're already a Debian dev/maintainer for some component ;)